# Unexpected <host> string in Elasticsearch index and alias names

Tags: elasticsearch, opensearch

Some of the indices and aliases in my Elasticsearch cluster have an unexpected `<host>` value in their names. I'm not sure who created them, unfortunately. I also can't find any mention of such a thing in any documentation, and the Elasticsearch APIs block index and alias names with brackets.

What is this `<host>` value from? How were these indices and aliases created?

Below is what I get when I query with elasticsearch-py:

**es.indices.get_alias()**

```
{
    "ip-172-31-1-1-example_index": {
        "aliases": {
            "ip-172-31-1-1-example_alias": {}
        }
    }
}
```

**es.cat.aliases()**

```
<host>-example_alias        <host>-example_index    - - - -
```

I am using elasticsearch-py 7.13.4 and Elasticsearch 7.10 engine on Amazon OpenSearch Service.